# Normality and integrality of schemes and splitting of map from structure sheaf to (derived)pushforward of structure sheaf along proper birational map

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, birational-geometry, derived-functors, pushforward

Let $R, S$ be commutative Noetherian rings such that $R$ is a subring of $S$. If $S$ is a normal domain, and there exists an $R$-linear map $\phi: S\to R$ whose restriction on $R$ is the identity map, then it is standard that $R$ is also a normal domain. This leads me to ask the following question:

Let $X, Y$ be Noetherian schemes such that $X$ is an integral and normal, and there exists a proper birational morphism $f: X\to Y$. If the natural map $\mathcal O_Y \to \mathbf Rf_*\mathcal O_X$ is a split monomorphism, then is $Y$ also a normal integral scheme?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the answer is yes, and that you don't need to assume a priori that the morphism is birational or proper, just quasicompact quasiseparated (for the pushforwards to be well-behaved). The statement can be checked Zariski locally on $Y$, so we may assume that $Y$ is affine. We have a factorization $\mathcal{O}_Y \to f_*(\mathcal{O}_X) \to Rf_*(\mathcal{O}_X)$. The composition $f_*(\mathcal{O}_X) \to Rf_*(\mathcal{O}_X) \to \mathcal{O}_Y$ with the assumed derived splitting induces a splitting of the morphism of rings $\mathcal{O}_Y \to f_*(\mathcal{O}_X)$. But now by https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0358, we know that $f_*(\mathcal{O}_X)$ is a normal domain, so according to what you claimed in the post this should imply that $\mathcal{O}_Y$ is also a normal domain. (By the way, what is a good reference for that fact in the post?).

Comment: What do you mean when you say ''$f_*\mathcal O_X$ is a normal domain"? This is not a ring, right...? Also, where do you use $f$ is quasi-compact quasi-separated?

Comment: A good place where an argument of the commutative algebra fact is written down is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4415425/a-question-related-to-normality-of-subring-of-a-normal-ring

Comment: I put myself in the situation where $Y$ is affine in the beginning of the answer. I am viewing $\mathcal{O}_Y$ as a ring $H^0(\mathcal{O}_Y)$ and identifying $f_*(\mathcal{O}_X) \cong  H^0(\mathcal{O}_X)$. Abusing notation slightly.

Comment: Similarly I just view $Rf_*(\mathcal{O}_X)$ as a complex of $H^0(\mathcal{O}_Y)$-modules here.

Comment: Quasicompact-quasiseparated is to ensure that the image $f_*$ is a quasicoherent sheaf and its formation commutes with passing to opens in the obvious way (similarly for $Rf_*(-)$). I am implicitly using quasicoherence in my implicit identifications. Regardless, if your morphism is between Noetherian schemes, then this is automatic. I was only pointing out something (quasicompactness) that would arise if you wanted to allow locally Noetherian schemes as source and target (and then quasiseparatedness is still automatic).

Comment: Wait, in the reference link you provided it is assumed that $S \to R$ is a ring homomorphism, not just any $R$-linear homomorphism. If it is a ring homomorphism then I agree that it is easy.

Comment: Let $a/b\in Q(R)\subseteq Q(S)$ be integral over $R$. Then, $a/b$ is integral over $S$, hence $a/b=s$ for some $s\in S$ as $S$ is normal. Thus, $a=bs$. Applying $\phi$, we get $a=b\phi(s)$. Thus, $bs=a=b\phi(s)$, hence $s=\phi(s)$ as $S$ is an integral domain. Thus, $a/b=\phi(s)\in R$, concluding our proof.

Comment: Ah, ok, great. Thank you for the explanation.